# C++ code to input function as string and then use the function ahead in the code

Tags: c++

I need to define functions in c++ code to be user defined. Basically that he writes the function in form of a string which is exact c++ code, then use that function in the very next line of code.

I have tried to append output to a file which is imported, but it obviously failed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, not interpreted (as Python is for example), you cannot execute code without compiling it. Unless you mean that your function is supposed to run gcc (or any other C++ compiler) and compile the given string, it's impossible.

Comment: You can't directly do this in C++ at all. There are workarounds, but they're non-trivial and platform-specific. Are you sure you really want to do this?

Comment: no way to compile it again through the code itself? Maybe I could compile it in a different thread but somehow use it after that in the main running code?

Comment: Why not use some other scripting language (python etc.) rather than c++?

Comment: @Useless Yes, I definitely want a workaround. I guess I wont mind platform specific as well

Comment: @G.M. This is just a part of the whole code, it uses a lot of other c++ functionalities

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? There are many scripting languages that can be *embedded* and used from C++ programs, is there a reason you cant use those? And have you thought of a *plugin* model, where you dynamically load "libraries" containing "plugins" conforming to a specific API?

Comment: If the desired code is not known at compilation time (i.e. you want to interpret code on the fly at runtime), and is C++ code, you'll need to compile it at runtime as well and call a process to execute it. Such functionality is way much easier to implement with scripting languages (Python, ...). I would suggest you to pass a Python script string and call it from your function.

Comment: If you really want a platform-specific solution, you _need to tell us your platform_. Honestly embedding a scripting language is likely to be better, though.

Comment: @Fareanor, Thanks. A simple python embedding seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) such as a mathematical formula.

To my knowledge, what you ask is not possible without

a) writing your own parser, that effectively creates functions from strings or

b) using external libraries - a quick google search brought be to [this library](http://warp.povusers.org/FunctionParser/fparser.html) that seems to provide the functionality you are looking for. I have no personal experience with it, though.

As @Useless pointed out, "editing" the code after compilation is not intended in a compiled language as c++. This could be tricked by having a second code compiled and executed in the background; this, however, seems rather unelegant and would rely on additional threads, compilers and the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do it. C++ code can not be interpreted at run-time. You may want to try [Qt/QML](https://www.qt.io/) which will give an opportunity to run a javascript code or an entire QML file from network/string or any other method which can deliver your code to the host application.